# Temp tables from another process and Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have taken over maintaining a stored procedure which relies on a session based temp table (#Table). The table was created in a stored procedure, and then my procedure is executed, referencing that temp table.

Functionally it works 100%, but when modifying the procedure, I have 'error' lines all over the place, as my proc doesn't know what #table is at design time. It's an asthetic issue, I know, but also, I lose code hints.

Is there a hint, or any work around to make my procedure know what #table structure is at design time?

Comment: manually create the temp table rather than use `select into` to create

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the creation of your temp table.

"Temp tables that are created within a SPID are accessible from any proceeding execution in that SPID."

http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/spid-what-is-it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a situation like this:

```
exec dbo.usp_CreateTempTable; -- creates the temp table
exec dbo.usp_ConsumeTempTable; -- uses the temp table created above
```

If that's the case, do the following in the second stored procedure

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#yourTempTable') is null
   create table #yourTempTable (
      «table definition goes here»
   );
```

That should placate Intellisense and yet not be run when you run under the conditions above. I'd put commentary around it saying "this table is expected to have been created from dbo.usp_CreateTempTable". This approach also has the benefit of documenting the temp table structure closer to where it's consumed.